# Altering table for adding foreign key constraint take very long time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have one table manual_errors_archive. I need to add foreign key to this table keeping reference to values table, values table having 800,000 records and manual_errors_archive table does not have any records.

```
ALTER TABLE manual_errors_archive 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_manua_reference_value 
FOREIGN KEY (value_id)
REFERENCES values;
```

Postgres version i am using 9.1
But this is running for more than 1 hr after that I canceled the process. Any idea how to optimize this process?

Comment: Maybe the statement just waits for a lock? Check `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity`: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring Are you *really* still using 8.4? You should upgrade **now**. 9.1 will be out of support in about 8 months as well.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name what to check and how to check that .I ran this query select t.relname,l.locktype,page,virtualtransaction,pid,mode,granted from pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t where l.relation=t.relid order by relation asc; butg how to conclude that?

Comment: what i have to do in that case .Do i have to release the lock and then i have to run the query.

Comment: You need to end the session that is blocking your `alter table` statement

Comment: I did not get..I ran the query SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity then several columns are displayed .How can i know whether lock is acquired or not ??

Comment: `pg_stat_activity` is explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW you are looking for sessions with `waiting = true`  or those that are related to rows in `pg_locks` with `granted = false` (as explained in the link of my first comment)